# Is there a way to make a “using” statement terminate before a nested one?

Tags: c#, using-statement

When a field is used for creating another field, and then disposed – I see two options. First:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image.GetThumbnailImage(32, 32, null, new IntPtr());
image.Dispose();//not needed anymore.

//use bitmap

bitmap.Dispose();
```

Second:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)image.GetThumbnailImage(32, 32, null, new IntPtr()))
    {
        //use bitmap
    }
}
```

The logical one would be the first (because the `Image` isn’t needed when the `Bitmap` is used), but `using` statements are generally preferable over `Dispose`.

Is there a third way – to terminate the first `using` inside the second one?

Comment: Is this a real problem for you?

Comment: @Oded Experience has shown that in order to avoid large refactoring of code – it should be written right the first time.

Comment: Have you heard about premature optimization? Being in the same method, the statements will go out of scope in about the same time and get collected together. I don't see what you have to gain.

Comment: Do note that `Dispose()` is immediate, while GC is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is: Put the code to produce the thumbnail image into a method:

```
Bitmap GetThumbnail(string path)
{
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        return (Bitmap)image.GetThumbnailImage(32, 32, null, new IntPtr());
    }
}

// ...

using (Bitmap bitmap = GetThumbnail(path))
{
    //use bitmap
}
```

**Please note:**
I agree with Oded's comments. I would use this code not because it disposes `image` first, but because it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a factory which will generate your own image : let's say it MyImage so MyImage must implements the IDisposable interface. After make a factory which will generate the images based on your rules use the using over you own image : MyImage.